# Countdown timer hour reset with history

Tags: php, jquery, countdown

I'm trying to make countdown timer that resets itself every 60 minutes and wont reset on every refresh.

I think the ideal way to do this is via timezone?

Comment: The timezone is not important, what have you tried?

Comment: Since HTTP is stateless, you would need to store the start time on the server in a PHP session (or a cookie, but server-side is better), and use that as the initialization time on each page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to perform this, but usually i'd recommend storing the unix-timestamp in a MySQL Database, then fetch and compare the previous/stored unix-timestamp with the current timestamp. The PHP-function time() will get you the current timestamp.

If the entire project is about making a counter, you can probably achieve the same effect by writing/loading from a text-file. The same goes for sessions.

Here's a little snippet to give you an idea of how to solve this:

```
if (($unixtime + (60 * 60)) > time()) //previous time + 60 * 60 sec (60 min).
{
//update counter
}

//present counter
```